# how to save modification (creation ,update of OWL file) into fuseki server

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki

I created an ontology model using protege. ,
I used java  to populate my ontology( reate user , resources..) 
and then I save all modification into a file.

Now I need to integrate an RDF server to save changes 
after some research I found that Fuseki is one of the best servers that I can use .. 
After some more research I also found that I need to use RDFCOnnexion to communicate with the fuseki server but I am having some difficulties with integrating the server and manipulating all of my Java classes.

To request my ontology , I used RDFconnexion:
example :
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    RDFConnection conn1 = 
   RDFConnectionFactory.connect("http://localhost:3030/test/") ;
    try( QueryExecution qExec = conn1.query("PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/> 
    SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o }") ) {
        ResultSet rs = qExec.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(rs, qExec.getQuery());
    }
     }
```

but I am running into issues trying to create the Agent (user) ,or resource..
below you will find just a part of my Java code :

```
private final OntModel onto;
private OntModel inferred;

public test() {
    onto = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
    OntDocumentManager manager = onto.getDocumentManager();
    manager.addAltEntry("http://www-test/1.0.0", "ontologies/test.owl");
  }

public String createUri(String prefix, String localName){
    String uri = prefix + "#" + localName ;
    uri = uri.replaceAll(" ", "_") ;
    return uri ;
}
// to create Agent 
public Resource createAgent(String uri) throws 
AlreadyExistingRdfResourceException {
    Resource agent = this.createEntity(uri) ;
    if (agent==null) return null ;

    Property prop ; Statement s ;
    s = ResourceFactory.createStatement(agent, RDF.type, 
    onto.getIndividual(EngineConstants.CD_Agent)) ;
    onto.add(s) ;

    this.synchronize();
    return agent ;
}
// TO get Agent Activty 
public Set<Resource> getAgentActivities(String agentUri){
    final String query = "SELECT ?entity WHERE { ?entity CD:hasAgent <"+ 
agentUri +">}" ;
    ResultSet resultSet = this.queryExec(this.getInferred(), query);
    return this.getRdfResources(resultSet, "entity") ;
}
```

I need to know if someone can help me and give me an example how I can use and integrate Fuseki to ( modify and request my ontology).

thank you for your help

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, I think you can improve your question by posting what exactly went wrong. Did you run into errors? If so please post them so users who are trying to help you have all the information they need.

Comment: How do you load the data into the `OntModel` in the code below? I don'T see any call that reads data. And **what exactly** does not work?

Comment: I read file data using this code public void read(String url){ URL u = test.class.getResource("/" + url); onto.read(u.getFile(), "RDF/XML"); } in my initial propogram i have any error My problem that how can i use RDFconnexion to load my OntoModel into Fuseki and how i can save all modification into my server

Answer (score 1):

Note you probably first want to retrieve your graph using the `fetch()` method - http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/rdfconnection/org/apache/jena/rdfconnection/RDFDatasetAccessConnection.html#fetch-java.lang.String- - which will be more efficient than querying for it as you do now e.g.

```
Model model = connection.fetch("http://your-graph-name");
```

If you are just using the default graph you can just do `connection.fetch()` to retrieve that.

Once you have the local copy modify it with Jena APIs as you desire.

You can then use the `put()` method to update a graph - http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/rdfconnection/org/apache/jena/rdfconnection/RDFConnection.html#put-java.lang.String-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model- - with your local changes e.g.

```
connection.put("http://your-graph-name", model);
```

This will overwrite the existing graph with the current contents of `model`.  Again if you are just using the default graph you can just do `connection.put(model)`.